# SQOOP is not able load SAP HANA driver

Tags: azure-hdinsight, sqoop

I am trying to import data from SAP HANA database onto Azure DataLake Store using SQOOP.
for this, I've downloaded the HDB client to connect to HANA database but I'm looking for the location to copy 'ngdbc.jar' to $SQOOP_HOME/lib. On HDInsight Cluster, am not able to see the environmental variable $SQOOP_HOME/lib, it seems to be blank. Can anybody point me to the right location on HDP - HDInsight Cluster.

Currently, I am encountering following error.

```
sshadmin@hn0-busea2:~$ sqoop import  --connect 'jdbc:sap://XXXXXXX0004.ms.XXXXXXX.com:30015/?database=HDB&user=XXXXXXXXX&password=XXXXXXXXXXXXX' --driver com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver \
```

> --query 'select * from XXX.TEST_HIERARCHY where $CONDITIONS' \
>   --target-dir 'adl://XXXXXXXXXXXXX.azuredatalakestore.net:443/hdi-poc-dl/SAP_TEST_HIERARCHY' \
>   --m 1;
>   Warning: /usr/hdp/2.4.2.4-5/accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
>   Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
>   17/01/18 10:34:26 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.4.2.4-5
>   17/01/18 10:34:26 WARN sqoop.ConnFactory: Parameter --driver is set to an explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set (via --connection-manager). Sqoop is going to fall back to org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager. Please specify explicitly which connection manager should be used next time.
>   17/01/18 10:34:26 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
>   17/01/18 10:34:26 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
>   17/01/18 10:34:26 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:856)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:744)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:767)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:270)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:241)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForQuery(SqlManager.java:234)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:304)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1845)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1645)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:148)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:184)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:226)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:235)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:244)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this path /usr/hdp/current/sqoop-client/lib/